# Parallel error with GridSearchCV, works fine with other methods

Tags: python, parallel-processing, scikit-learn, grid-search

I am encounteringt the following problems using GridSearchCV: it gives me a parallel error while using `n_jobs > 1`. At the same time `n_jobs > 1` works fine with the single models like RadonmForestClassifier.

Below is a simple working example showing the errors:

```
train = np.random.rand(100,10)
targ = np.random.randint(0,2,100)

clf = ensemble.RandomForestClassifier(n_jobs = 2)
clf.fit(train,targ)
train = np.random.rand(100,10)
targ = np.random.randint(0,2,100)
​
clf = ensemble.RandomForestClassifier(n_jobs = 2)
clf.fit(train,targ)
Out[349]: RandomForestClassifier(bootstrap=True, class_weight=None,     criterion='gini',
            max_depth=None, max_features='auto', max_leaf_nodes=None,
            min_impurity_split=1e-07, min_samples_leaf=1,
            min_samples_split=2, min_weight_fraction_leaf=0.0,
            n_estimators=10, n_jobs=2, oob_score=False, random_state=None,
            verbose=0, warm_start=False)
```

this example works fine.

Meanwhile the following doesn't work:

```
clf = ensemble.RandomForestClassifier()
param_grid = {'n_estimators': [10,20]}
grid_s= model_selection.GridSearchCV(clf, param_grid=param_grid_gb,n_jobs=-1,verbose=1)
grid_s.fit(train, targ)
```

And gives the following error:

```
Fitting 3 folds for each of 2 candidates, totalling 6 fits

ImportErrorTraceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-351-b8bb45396026> in <module>()
      2 param_grid = {'n_estimators': [10,20]}
      3 grid_s= model_selection.GridSearchCV(clf, param_grid=param_grid_gb,n_jobs=-1,verbose=1)
----> 4 grid_s.fit(train, targ)

/root/anaconda3/envs/python2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sklearn/model_selection/_search.pyc in fit(self, X, y, groups)
    943             train/test set.
    944         """
--> 945         return self._fit(X, y, groups, ParameterGrid(self.param_grid))
    946 
    947 

/root/anaconda3/envs/python2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sklearn/model_selection/_search.pyc in _fit(self, X, y, groups, parameter_iterable)
    562                                   return_times=True, return_parameters=True,
    563                                   error_score=self.error_score)
--> 564           for parameters in parameter_iterable
    565           for train, test in cv_iter)
    566 

/root/anaconda3/envs/python2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sklearn/externals/joblib/parallel.pyc in __call__(self, iterable)
    726         self._aborting = False
    727         if not self._managed_backend:
--> 728             n_jobs = self._initialize_backend()
    729         else:
    730             n_jobs = self._effective_n_jobs()

/root/anaconda3/envs/python2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sklearn/externals/joblib/parallel.pyc in _initialize_backend(self)
    538         try:
    539             return self._backend.configure(n_jobs=self.n_jobs, parallel=self,
--> 540                                            **self._backend_args)
    541         except FallbackToBackend as e:
    542             # Recursively initialize the backend in case of requested fallback.

/root/anaconda3/envs/python2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sklearn/externals/joblib/_parallel_backends.pyc in configure(self, n_jobs, parallel, **backend_args)
    297         if already_forked:
    298             raise ImportError(
--> 299                 '[joblib] Attempting to do parallel computing '
    300                 'without protecting your import on a system that does '
    301                 'not support forking. To use parallel-computing in a '

ImportError: [joblib] Attempting to do parallel computing without protecting your import on a system that does not support forking. To use parallel-computing in a script, you must protect your main loop using "if __name__ == '__main__'". Please see the joblib documentation on Parallel for more information
```

Answer (score 13):

I think you are using windows. You need to wrap the grid search in a function and then call inside `__name__ == '__main__'`. Joblib parallel `n_jobs=-1` determines the number of jobs to use which in parallel doesn't work on windows all the time.

Try wrapping grid search in a function:

```
def somefunction():
    clf = ensemble.RandomForestClassifier()
    param_grid = {'n_estimators': [10,20]}
    grid_s= model_selection.GridSearchCV(clf,   param_grid=param_grid_gb,n_jobs=-1,verbose=1)
    grid_s.fit(train, targ)
    return grid_s

if __name__ == '__main__':
    somefunction()
```

Or:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    clf = ensemble.RandomForestClassifier()
    param_grid = {'n_estimators': [10,20]}
    grid_s= model_selection.GridSearchCV(clf,   param_grid=param_grid_gb,n_jobs=-1,verbose=1)
    grid_s.fit(train, targ)
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll try this but at the moment I am on a linux server. Edit: I just tried your solution and it still gives me the same error.

Comment: @Alessandro does it work if everything is inside the main? (see edited answer).

Comment: no, same error! Wierd thing is that the model itself works.

Comment: Sorry to bump this thread. I am still having this problem even after trying both the solutions. The issue exists even if I try `n_jobs=2`. I am using Windows 7 x64 bit OS and Python 3.6.4. Any way to get around this??

Comment: @Code_Sipra have you tried upgrading to the latest _joblib_ package (version 0.12.2)? In my conda environment I needed to do this, as well as putting all my code that wasn't an import or function under the `if __name__ == '__main__':` like @Abhishek;s 2nd suggestion

Comment: I tried @humbleHacker.. But the problem exists. Even tried on a windows 10 machine.

Comment: Nice answer @AbhishekThakur. However, it is not clear from your answer how can you return the best classifier from the `__name__ == '__main__'` where the grid search function is called to main script back again so that you can do some more stuff with it (e.g. metrics etc)?

Answer (score 2):

Maybe this could be still relevant for some!

I tried this only **using Anaconda on a Windows 10 machine**:

I had the same problem within my environment, with the following code section:

```
parameters = [{'C': [1, 10, 100, 1000], 'kernel': ['linear']}, {'C': [1, 10, 100, 1000], 'kernel': ['rbf'], 'gamma': [0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5, 0.6, 0.7, 0.8, 0.9]}]

grid_search = GridSearchCV(estimator = classifier, param_grid = parameters, scoring = 'accuracy', cv = 10, n_jobs = -1)
grid_search = grid_search.fit(X_train, y_train)
best_accuracy = grid_search.best_score_
best_parameters = grid_search.best_params_
```

I did not find a lot on the internet, so I thought maybe I should update the joblib class. And surprise - **joblib was not installed in my specific environment**. After I installed and updated it - it worked perfectly. With `n_jobs = -1` AND `n_jobs = 2`.

Comment: Same for me. Solved. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me was changing the parallel backend:

```
from sklearn.utils import parallel_backend

with parallel_backend('multiprocessing'):  # 'multiprocessing' / 'threading'
    # GridSearchCV code...
```

See acceptable `backend` values [here](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.utils.parallel_backend.html).

Answer taken from [here](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/issues/14298#issuecomment-509702572).