# Parallel error with GridSearchCv, RandomSearchCV. Works fine with single models

Tags: parallel-processing, grid-search

I am having a similar problem on this link: [Parallel error with GridSearchCV, works fine with other methods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40803684/parallel-error-with-gridsearchcv-works-fine-with-other-methods#)

I tried both of the solutions and neither one worked for me, as well.

When n_jobs = -1 in a grid search I get an error although n_jobs = -1 works fine for single models.

I tried updating sklearn but it did not help.

Here is the code I am trying:

```
rf = RandomForestClassifier()
rf_random = RandomizedSearchCV(estimator=rf, 
                          param_distributions = random_grid,
                          n_iter = 100, cv = 3,  verbose = 2, random_state = 42, 
                          n_jobs = -1)
rf_random.fit(X_train, y_train)
```

I am getting this error:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 
'sklearn.externals.joblib.externals.loky.backend.popen_loky_win32'
```

Tried the solution on the link but got the same error:

```
def randomsearcher():
    clf = ensemble.RandomForestClassifier()
    param_grid = random_grid
    grid_s= model_selection.GridSearchCV(clf, cv=5,  param_grid=param_grid 
                                    ,n_jobs=-1,verbose=1)
    grid_s.fit(X_train,y_train)
    return grid_s

if __name__ == '__main__':
randomsearcher()
```

No problem with this code:

```
knn = KNeighborsClassifier(n_neighbors=50, 
weights='distance',algorithm='auto',n_jobs = -1 )
```

I am working on a VM that has 8 virtual processors on 2 sockets.